# Delphi multiline regex

Tags: regex, delphi

I have some non-regression test code in Delphi that calls an external diff tool. Then my code loads the diff results and should remove acceptable differences, such as dates in the compared results. I'm trying to do this with a multiline [TRegEx.Replace](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Replace) , but no match is found ...

https://regex101.com/r/QBZuws/2 shows the pattern I came up with and a sample test diff file. I need to delete the matching "pararaphs" of 3 lines

Here is my code :

```
function FilterDiff(AText:string):string;
var
  LStr:string;
  Regex: TRegEx;
begin
  // AText:=StringReplace(AText,#13+#10,'\n',[rfReplaceAll]); // doesn't help ...
  LStr := '\d\d.\d\d.20\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d'; // regex for date and time
  LStr := '@@.*@@\n-'+LStr+'\n\+'+LStr; // regex for paragraphs to remove
  Regex := TRegEx.Create(LStr, [roMultiLine]);
  Result := Regex.Replace(AText,'');
end;

procedure TReportTest.NonRegression;
var
  LDiff : TStringList;
  // others removed for clarity
begin
  // removed section code that call an external tool and produces diff.txt file
  LDiff := TStringList.Create;
  LDiff.LoadFromFile('diff.txt');
  Status(FilterDiff(LDiff.Text)); // show the diffs in DUnit GUI for now
  LDiff.Free;
end;
```

Besides, while tracing TRegEx.Replace down to

```
System.RegularExpressionsAPI.pcre_exec($4D72A50,nil,'--- '#$D#$A'+++ '#$D#$A'@@ -86 +86 @@'#$D#$A'-16.11.2017 15:00:36'#$D#$A'+15.11.2017 10:47:58'#$D#$A'@@ -400 +400 @@'#$D#$A'-16.11.2017 15:00:36'#$D#$A'+15.11.2017 10:47:58'#$D#$A,132,0,1024,$7D56800,300)
System.RegularExpressionsCore.TPerlRegEx.Match
System.RegularExpressionsCore.TPerlRegEx.ReplaceAll
System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Replace(???,???)
TestReportAuto.FilterDiff('--- '#$D#$A'+++ '#$D#$A'@@ -86 +86 @@'#$D#$A'-16.11.2017 15:00:36'#$D#$A'+15.11.2017 10:47:58'#$D#$A'@@ -400 +400 @@'#$D#$A'-16.11.2017 15:00:36'#$D#$A'+15.11.2017 10:47:58'#$D#$A)
```

I was surprised to see quotes before and after each newline #$D#$A in the debugger, but they don't look "real" ... or are they ?

Comment: Single quote `'` is a string delimiter. Needs to be escaped to be an actual quote, `''`. So, what you can see are delimiters. The documentation should make this clear. I suggest you review it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : yes that's ok now. Was surprised to see #$D#$A concatenated this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you seem to have issues with different kinds of line breaks, I would recommend to adjust your Regex to use `\R` instead of `\n` which matches Windows style linebreaks (CR + LF) as well as Unix style linebreaks (LF).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I just noticed the \n in regex matches only LF, not CR+LF, so I added

```
AText:=StringReplace(AText,#13+#10,#10,[rfReplaceAll]); // \n matches only LF !
```

at the beginning of my function and it's much better now...
Sometimes writing down a problem helps ...